# admob not implementing in react native using expo

Tags: react-native, expo, admob, documentation, ads

Can someone provide me the official expo documentation that how I can integrate admob ads in react native, because I havn't find any official doc, i have tried almost tuns of articles, docs, youtube videos. This is my first time implementing admob ads.

Comment: Standard Expo Go, will not support the Admob package. You need to compile a custom Dev Client and pre-embed https://docs.page/invertase/react-native-google-mobile-ads